# Perform Word mail merge programmatically using NetOffice

Tags: .net, netoffice

I'm trying out [NetOffice](https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/NetOffice) to perform MS Word mail merge using a template and programatically filling in the merge fields. The examples available [here](https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/NetOffice/tree/master/Examples/Word/C%23/Standard%20Examples) does not really have this scenario. I updated Example 03 in it so that it creates a new document from an existing MS Word document with merge fields. I then changed it to access the merge fields using the code below:

```
var fields = newDocument.MailMerge.Fields;
foreach (Word.MailMergeField field in fields)
{
   ...
}
```

But the `for` loop gets this exception the first time it tries to enumerate through fields: *Factory is not initialized with NetOffice assemblies.* If I try to run on debug, `fields.Count` returns a correct count of the merge fields on my document. I just can't seem to access the fields to fill/update them.

Has anyone encountered this before?

**UPDATE**

Running a debug on `Core.cs`, it fails to load the assembly from `WordApi.dll`, and consequently does not get the FactoryInfo from that assembly, which I assume it needs in its `_factoryList`. I haven't quite figured out why it is failing to load the assembly even when the dll is in the folder that it is searching in.

Comment: This was bug in some NetOfficeFw packages. When you update to latest NetOfficeFw packages from https://www.nuget.org/profiles/netoffice you will get fixed version of NetOffice libraries.

Comment: I was getting the same error in Outlook at `Dim oAccounts = oOutlook.Session.Accounts`. I switched to the FW version of the package and it worked. What's the difference between the two, and may I ask why you chose not to publish the update/fix to the non-FW version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I'm getting appears to be a bug on NetOffice. The bug is in the `CurrentAppDomain` class'  [`LoadFrom()`](https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/NetOffice/blob/master/Source/NetOffice/CurrentAppDomain.cs#L149). Given it is accepting the assembly's full file path (and not the assembly's fully qualified name), it should perform an `Assembly.LoadFrom(path)` if `LoadAssembliesUnsafe` is false.

I have reported this bug/issue on github. [Link here.](https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/NetOffice/issues/3)